# Image save path

Tags: android, cordova, image-capture

i am making a **Android** application using **PhoneGap**. After capturing the image, i want the `saved path` of that image into the **textfield**.

So please help me how to get the path or any tutorial will be also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it help you but i found [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/kaddSxhnPyM) and [this one as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303155/android-phonegap-how-to-get-the-file-name-of-the-picture-taken)

hope it help. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but it is not working , let i will try one more time. thanks